# Projeto Xamarin cross platform inicia com erros

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform

Projeto Cross Platform no Visual Studio já abre com 31 erros, talvez seja apenas configurações da IDE. Se alguém já se deparou com esse problema, segue um exemplo dos erros que surgem.

[image: erros]

Comment: Você já fez o restore dos pacotes nuget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema reportado pode estar relacionado a algum arquivo desatualizado. Tente realizar os passos abaixo:

- Clean Solution;
- Restore NuGet Packages;
- Rebuild Solution.

Caso não funcionar, tente atualizar o Xamarin em Tools>Options>Xamarin>Other>Check Updates.